# why couldn't MX records point to an ip directly?

Tags: dns, mx-record

When I set DNS of my domain name, I find MX cannot point to an ip address. It must point to another domain name. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the RDATA field in the MX record is defined (by RFC1035) to contain a 16-bit integer (the preference value) and a domain name. While it is always possible to encode an IP address as a domain name, there is no way to specify that that's what you did. So anyone reading the field would have to guess if the data is supposed to be a name or an address. Rather than have this ambiguity, the standards say that you must use a name.